# Terraform: Replace function not working inside for_each while creating a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

While creating one of the resource using *for_each*, I am also getting the info from other resource to populate data to one of the attribute in the resource creation. However I need to replace the *each.value* part to match properly and get the response from other resource, but wierdly, the replace function doesn't seem to do it's job. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Code sample is below. While creating route 53 record, trying to get the info from cloud_front resource.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "redirect-records" {
  for_each = var.redirects
  zone_id  =  data.aws_route53_zone.main[each.value.domain_tf_alias].zone_id  
  name     = each.value.source
  type     = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = **aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[replace(each.value.source,".","-")].domain_name** 
    zone_id                = **aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[replace(each.value.source,".","-")].hosted_zone_id**
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Expected: I need the **each.value.source** say example from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to be replaced to www-example-com, but that is not happening.

```
Error: Invalid index

  on rules.tf line 25, in resource "aws_route53_record" "redirect-records":
  25:     name                   = aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[replace(each.value.source,".","-")].domain_name # If acm domain exists then get from cloudFront else from S3
    |----------------
    | aws_cloudfront_distribution.main is object with 4 attributes
    | each.value.source is "www.aclgrc-s3.com"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: What is `var.redirects`?

Comment: Also why do you think it does not work? Any error messages?

Comment: Yes, Let me share an error message.

Comment: I have included the error message. var.redirects is an array of map objects. And source is an url like www.example.com, support.helloworld.com etc. I need them to be replaced with www-example-com and support-helloworld-com.

Comment: the `replace` works correctly. I would double check what are the actual keys in your `aws_cloudfront_distribution.main`.

Comment: When I give **aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[www-aclgrc-s3-com].domain_name**, it works correctly.

Comment: You can open tf console, `terraform console` and test there with `replace("www.aclgrc-s3.com",".","-")`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227782/discussion-between-manjunath-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion.

The issue is not with the `replace` function. The function works exactly as expected.

The issue is caused by the **mismatch of keys** in `var.redirects` and `aws_cloudfront_distribution.main`. Subsequently, the solution is to ensure that the two data sets have matching keys.